# When to upvote an answer

Tags: discussion

What must be the rule for upvoting an answer?

Must I upvoted every good answer or only the best one in a question?

Must I upvoted a minimal correct answer even if *trivial* answer? I'm thinking about an answer like "use a pull-up resistor" that just solve the problem.

Must I upvote a correct answer in every question I look at?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there can be any fixed rule, you have to go with you gut.

Normally I wouldn't up vote all answers, because it neutralises the vote if you vote for them all, but sometimes all the answers are good and you have to.

Personally I would down vote the answer "use a pull up resistor".  It doesn't explain **why** and that's more important.  I come here to learn things, and if I can share what I know, an instruction to do something fixes the immediate problem but doesn't fix the long term problem.

**BUT** that's just my opinion and you should go with yours. :)

Comment: I like your criteria: "instruction to do something fixes the immediate problem but doesn't fix the long term problem"

Answer (score 0):

> Must I upvote every good answer or only the best one in a question?

You don't *have* to up-vote anything. You might do nothing if, for example, the question and answer are not in your area of expertise (eg. the ESP8266). Sometimes people ask questions about some device I know nothing about. Therefore I can't say if the answer is good or bad, so I move on without voting.

If there are two or more answers I would be tempted to up-vote the better one. Sometimes they are both good so I will up-vote both of them.

> Must I upvote a correct answer in every question I look at?

No you don't. However remember how the reputation system works. Other users get reputation when you up-vote, and that helps them to get more tools to work with the site (like editing questions).

Up-voting also helps the person asking the question (they will probably choose the answer with the most up votes), and also others who look at the question later.

---

Down voting is useful if you think an answer is clearly wrong (or maybe doesn't even clearly answer the question). In those cases you can also add a comment (although you are not *required* to) explaining why you think the answer is wrong. These comments can help other people understand why an answer has down votes.

---

For really bad answers (like spam, or abuse) you can flag them for moderator attention. However don't flag answers that are just wrong, voting down is the correct approach there.

Comment: Help Center left things unexplained, like what "flag" means. I thought "flag" is something you do when you don't have the "close" option due low reputation. In the Help Center main page there is no "flag" entry. Now I know.